# How do I change the application background color at run-time in a Flex 3.5 application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a Flex 3.5 application that will serve multiple purposes, and as part of the visual changes that I'd like to make to indicate which mode the application is in, I want to change its background color.

Currently, the application tag looks like this:

```
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns:com="ventures.view.component.*"
    xmlns:views="ventures.view.*"
    layout="absolute"
    preinitialize="onPreInitialize()"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
    applicationComplete="onApplicationComplete()"
    click="onClick(event)"
    enabled="{(!chainController.generalLocked)}"
    backgroundGradientColors="[0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF]"
>
```

I've tried using a binding, for both the `backgroundColor` and `backgroundGradientColors` attributes:

```
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    ...
    backgroundColor="{app_background_color}"
>
```

—and—

```
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    ...
    backgroundGradientColors="{app_background_color}"
>
```

but for the former binding is not allowed, and for the latter there is a warning that:

> Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "app_background_color".

I also ran across [this page](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=176683) which seems to indicate that I could do it with the `setStyle()` method, but [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_08.html) seems to indicate that this method is only available for components, not the main canvas.

I suppose I could wrap everything in a `<mx:Canvas></mx:Canvas>` specificially for this purpose, but that seems wasteful—like Div-itis in HTML or something.

What's the best way to change the main application background color at run-time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("Application").setStyle('backgroundColor', 'Red');
```

Comment: This is how the [Flex 3 Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html) works, but I'm not yet able to get it working in my application. Going to dig in further to see if there's something else preventing it from working.

Comment: I ended up removing the `backgroundColor`/`backgroundGradientColors` definitions from my application tag, and setting the color explicitly to be one or the other in onApplicationComplete. Doing that, this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like if your mx:Application tag uses the backgroundColor attribute you need to do this:

```
mx.core.Application.application.setStyle('backgroundColor','green');
```